# Changing library location

Tags: rmysql

So I'm relatively new to using r-studio and I'm having a problem installing RMySQL.

I'm running RStudio 0.98.501 and R 3.0.2 and trying to connect R to a database. However, whenever I try to install RMySQL I get the error message "package ‘RMySQL’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)". When I searched I found this thread: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/RMySQL-with-Windows-7-td4684805.html which explains how I could be downloading packages to Program Files. I checked using the .libPaths() function and this was confirmed ("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library"). I guess my question is how do I change the library path so that I can install RMySQL? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the instructions here posted [here](http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/).

Basically what you have to do is:

- install MySQL from the Oracle homepage
- install RTools
- change your system variable "MYSQL_HOME" to match your MySQL installation
- (in some cases ibmysql.dll which is part of your MySQL installation had to be copied from lib folder to bin folder so it could be found)

That should (hopefully) do the trick although I did not stumble upon any remark stating RMySQL installation (especially under Windows) is easy.